# How can i get article owner user_id and save to notifiable_id field

Tags: laravel, notify

How can i get article owner user_id and save to notifiable_id field 
Suppos 
$articlecomment = $article_owner_id

My code:

```
$articlecomment = new Article_comment();
$articlecomment->user_id  = Auth::user()->id;//Comment by user id
$articlecomment->article_id = $request->articleid;
$articlecomment->comment    = $request->comment;
$articlecomment->save();   
auth()->user()->notify(new ArticleNotification($articlecomment));
//$articlecomment->user()->notify(new ArticleNotification($articlecomment));
```

Database Screenshot
i want article_owner_user_id on notifible_id field
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YE9SN.png)

Comment: Can you please explain a little more where do you want that id, your question does not have much information

Comment: Suppos $articlecomment = $article_owner_id

I want this id to notifications table notifiable_id column 
Owner of this article who will notify "Someone commented on your article"

Comment: Suppose Article owner id is "5" and login user id 6 when login user comment on this article it will notify Article Owner for that i want to store this article_owner id to notifiable_id
When i use this auth()->user()->notify(new ArticleNotification($articlecomment)); it will store login user_id but i need Article owner id

Answer (score 1):

```
Solved 
 $articlecomment->save();
 $article = Article::where('id','=',$request->articleid)->first();
 if($article->user_id != Auth::User()->id){
 $article->user->notify(new ArticleNotification($article));
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a relationship set up for your `Article_comment` and `Article` models, you can access the "Article Owner" through the relation.

For example, define a relation for your "Article" model inside your `Article_comment` class (assuming `Article` is the name of your model):

```
class Article_comment extends Model {
    ....

    public function article() {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Article', 'id', 'article_id')
    }

    ....
}
```

Once you have that set, you can access your relation (and subsequent properties) like so (assuming `article_owner_id` is a property of your `Article` model):

```
$articlecomment->article->article_owner_id
```

**Edit:**

Whichever user you call notify on will notify that user. So to notify the article owner, you will need to get the user of the article and call notify from that instance (rather than the auth user). If you set up a relation to the user on your Article class, you can simply call notify from that, or get the user from the `article_owner_id` and call notify.

Example:

```
$user = User::where('id', '=', $articlecomment->article->article_owner_id)->first();
$user->notify(new ArticleNotification($articlecomment));
```

With a relation set on your Article class, you could instead call notify like this:

```
$articlecomment->article->user->notify(new ArticleNotification($articlecomment));
```

For more info on Eloquent relationships, see https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#introduction

Comment: I have use laravel default notification system
and i am trying to store notify user id if someone comment article than owner of this article need to get notify
If i use 
auth()->user()->notify(new ArticleNotification($articlecomment));
It will store current user id and notify that user who comment on this article but i want to notify article owner 

When i use 
$article_owner_id = "10";
on this
$articlecomment->.......->..........->notify(new ArticleNotification($articlecomment));

Answer (score 0):

[This is database i need article_owner_id on notifible_id field click here to see screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HPxJp.png)